# Ubuntu 20.04 Gimp, not able to add fonts because error

Tags: fonts, gimp

I just installed gimp and was having fun with it. I wanted to add new fonts.
I opened GIMP and went to preferences and files then fonts and at last I clicked the fonts folder and tried to open file location. All it gave me was this error:

[image]

Can someone please help me by telling me how to solve this problem?

Thanks, this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove snap and install normal deb version by

```
sudo snap remove gimp

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: I'll try thank you!

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Comment: Thank you so much! This also fixed the problem I was having that was prompting me to not either use Gimp or Ubuntu when graphic editing. Thanks so much!